# WSO2 - Unable to start traffic manager in API Manager distributed setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have been trying to setup the WSO2 API Manager in a distributed setup. I have made all the configurations and it got started. But when I changed the key store by creating a new key store, the Traffic manager and other profiles are not getting started. I am getting the below error while starting the different profiles of API Manager after setting up the key store.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
```

I followed this link - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#adding-ca-signed-certificates-to-keystores for setting up a new key store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: alias should be wso2carbon, if you change it you have to change alias name in config

Comment: Thanks, it works now.  If you can add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I'm unable to login to the publisher and dev portal after changing the alias. Getting the below exception - org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Cannot find the primary certificate for tenant carbon.super - @Bera

Comment: use existing .jks file, remove the existing certificate chain, and generate a new one (recommend https://keystore-explorer.org/) with a name wso2carbon and replace existing jks files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alias should be wso2carbon, if you change it you have to change alias name in config